# Is there a level of commitment I should have before joining a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion

I found an answer on a Stack Exchange site I infrequently visit that I thought was very good. I went to upvote it, but realized I wasn't a member of that Stack Exchange site yet. If I joined it, in all likelihood I'd end up upvoting one answer then never using the site again (I realize that might not be the case, but for the sake of the question let's assume it is).

It occurred to me there's probably a reason we aren't all added to every Stack Exchange site when we make our accounts. Considering all the thought put into this site, I seriously doubt it simply went unconsidered (by the way, I agree with this choice).

My best guess is that letting users pick and choose their Stack Exchange sites allows them to personalize their accounts more, and more easily get to Stack Exchange sites which interest them. After all, I don't speak German, so why would I need to scroll past that Stack Exchange site to get to Stack Overflow?

If that's the case, then joining a Stack Exchange site just to upvote an answer seems fine. But if this choice was made for some performance or statistical reason, then maybe one upvote isn't worth it.

Is there a level of commitment I should have before joining a Stack Exchange site? To make this question less case-specific, you can remove the detail of upvoting one answer; I just added that for context. A better extreme is a user joining a Stack Exchange site "just because" with no intention of contributing. I understand there wouldn't be a brightline for when you're "committed enough", but even if the answer's "only join if you plan on contributing", that's helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The database can handle it, so don't avoid creating an account just for fear of adding load.  I mean, SO is way bigger than any other site and *it* can handle it -- I think they've even turned off the automatic culling of unused accounts there.

I have accounts on some sites only because I saw something that needed to be flagged.  (And I'm not even one of the people monitoring Smoke Detector -- those folks do this all the time.)  I've never seen any indication that this is viewed negatively by anybody.

My only *teeny, tiny* caution would be, when voting, to make sure you're voting because the content is good/helpful and not just because something you came across (perhaps via Hot Network Questions) was funny or snarky or otherwise entertaining.  Remember that the association bonus gives you an upvote but *not* a downvote, so please take an extra moment to ask yourself if your vote will help good content rise to the top.  But if the content deserves your upvote, then please go ahead and cast it if you have the privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Any statistic worth their name can handle people coming for one upvote and never returning. The databases will be fine as well. If someone offers a registration button it's their job to live with the consequences if you press it.

I have accounts for all sorts of reasons. Wanting to ask something and decided differently while doing so and never coming back. Giving single upvotes, giving single upvotes on meta, flagging stuff being the least *helpful* ones.

Either way as long as you don't join up to troll in the comments go for it.